# want to know the syntax meaning

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

can anyone explain the the below syntax what it is doing and if i have donation amount as 12345.67889889, if i want to load only 12345.67 what i have to change in above syntax.

```
DONATION_AMOUNT NULLIF DONATION_AMOUNT = BLANKS DEFAULTIF DONATION_AMOUNT = 'NULL' "REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(:DONATION_AMOUNT),'[,/$]')",
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use CAST  `cast(round(DONATION_MOUNT) as numeric(x,2))` where x is the max amount in digits

Answer (score 0):

```
NULLIF DONATION_AMOUNT = BLANKS
  If the donation_amount field in the file is blank, set it to NULL in the table.

DEFAULTIF DONATION_AMOUNT = 'NULL'
  If the donation_amount field in the file = the string 'NULL', set it to NULL in the table.

"REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(:DONATION_AMOUNT),'[,/$]')"
  The TRIM() call removes blanks from either end of the string read from the file, 
then removes commas, slashes and dollar signs.
```

To truncate to 2 decimal places in addition to the above rules, wrap it in a REGEXP_SUBSTR() which  matches 1 or more numbers anchored to the start of the string, followed by a decimal point, followed by up to 2 optional numbers.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(:DONATION_AMOUNT),'[,/$]'), '^\d+\.\d?\d?', 1, 1)
```